# what's wrong with my pdo prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

what am i doing wrong? i know for a fact has something to do w/ the prepared statement. thanks!

EDIT: here's all the code for the script so everyone can see what's going on. I'm having to add more words right now b/c the form doesn't like how much code i'm adding.

```
<?  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    include_once("includes/connect.php");       

    session_start();

    $error = array();
    $success = "The artist has been added!";

    if(!empty($_POST['artist-name'])){
        $artistName = $_POST['artist-name'];
    } else{
        $error[] = "Please enter a valid artist name!";
    }

    if(empty($error)){          

        //prepared statement goes here "INSERT INTO artist VALUES(?)"
        try{
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO artist(name) VALUES(:artist)");
            $stmt->execute(array("artist" => $artistName));
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                print_r($row);
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        //$_SESSION["success"] = $success;

    } else {
        $_SESSION["error"] = $error;
    }

    header("Location: ../add-artist.php");
    exit();                             

}
?>
```

Comment: did you receive any error message?

Comment: What's happening or not happening? *"Here's some code, tell me if it works and why not"* is hard to answer.

Comment: just a 500 internal server error message. i added error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); at one point but it didn't get rid of the 500 message

Comment: Check your error logs. 500 is just thrown by Apache not knowing what else to do, PHP and/or Apache will have logged the error somewhere though.

Comment: @deceze my script runs fine up until this part. i think this is just a syntax error w/ my prepared statement. that's why i haven't included anything else.

Comment: Is it a mysql syntax error? Tried to define column name explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO artist VALUES(:artist)");
```

The parameter is called `:artist`.

```
$stmt->execute(array('artist' => $artistName));
```

You're calling it with `artist`. The colon should be there too, even though it's added internally.

Regarding the error, the only ones that wouldn't get caught by exceptions in this case would be fatal errors. Having `error_reporting = -1` and `display_errors = On` in the php.ini should make the error visible. Otherwise, use the `error_log` .ini setting.

Comment: It should work without the colon.

Comment: @Jack, thanks but i tried that and that didn't fix it. i still got the error.

Comment: @heyjohnmurray What's *the* error?

Comment: like i said i tried adding error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); to show me more specific errors but that didnt do anything. any other suggestion on how to get it to output THE error. thanks

Comment: @pfyod That behaviour should not be relied upon because it's not documented.

Comment: @Jack the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''ERROR: '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MusicLibraryApp/scripts/add-artist-post.php on line 27. this refers to the catch echo in the try/catch statement

Comment: @heyjohnmurray The code shown doesn't seem to have any parse errors though; perhaps you're not closing a string properly earlier?

Comment: hmmm. i'll keep working on it. thanks for the help. at least my errors are turned on now. small victory. thanks for your patience.

Comment: @heyjohnmurray There are still no parse errors in the posted code.

Comment: i give up for the night. i'll come back to it when it's not 3am. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jack so among other things. one of the things that i found was that i was missing `$stmt->bingParam(":artist", $artistName);` after my prepare statement.

Comment: @heyjohn you don't need bindParam() if you pass the arguments via execute()